# How to apply Pod Limit range for Hierarchical Namespace in kubernetes GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How to apply Pod Limit range for Hierarchical Namespace in kubernetes GKE cluster. I am able to apply HierarchicalResourceQuota on HNS but not finding any option for LimitRange

Comment: When you say that you didn't find an option for LimitRange, were you looking for the option in the GCP console? Or did you try to do it using the configuration YAML file and it didn't work?

Comment: [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) you can find the official Kubernetes doc for Limit Range along with a few [samples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/#what-s-next) to follow on how to do it.